# Css code for restricting submit button when fields are blank

Tags: css, submit-button

I need CSS code to restrict submit button if fields are empty.Daily we are receiving 3-5 blank inquiries through our WordPress landing page submit button.

Where to put these CSS codes if any.

Thanks

Comment: well, first off, generally such things are done in javascript instead of in CSS. Depending on the exact (html) structure of the form though, it **may (only in certain cases)** be possible to hide the submit button (while the textbox `value=""`) in CSS. -- Generally an even better approach (in addition to the javascript) is to filter the submission serverside in PHP for example.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if we can do it in CSS aswell

Comment: Its not super likely, but if the `text` input and the `submit` input happen to be siblings in the html code , then it is possible using the css `+` selector.

Answer (score 2):

You really should do this with a script, because doing something like this by CSS is very sensitive to any future changes to your form structure.
It can be done with only CSS, using the `:placeholder-shown` selector.
For this you'll need to add a placeholder to all text inputs.

```css
/* As long as one of the selectors is matched, the button won't show. */
form input:placeholder-shown ~ button,
form textarea:placeholder-shown ~ button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
first name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter first name"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter last name"><br>
Text area<br>
<textarea name="textarea" placeholder="Enter some text..."></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will work, but for any change in the form you'll need to make sure it doesn't break.
I personally won't use this :)